# NETSUITE: Getting error while transforming sales order into invoice with REST API

Tags: rest, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I have a sales order in Netsuite and I'm trying to invoice a part of the sales order to have to possibility to invoice multiple time the customer.
I tried differents ways but each time I'm getting an error.

The Sales order have 3 item for the first line and 2 for the second line

URL: {{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/salesorder/18657/!transform/invoice

```
{
    "trandate":"2023-11-21",
    "startdate":"2023-11-21",
    "duedate":"2023-12-31",
    "memo": "This is apostman test!",
    "externalid":"PO000093",
    "salesrep":"209",
    "tranId": "T2023000024",
    "item":{
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "item": {
                    "id" : "578"
                },
                "quantity" : 1.00
            },
            {
                "item": {
                    "id" : "578"
                },
                "quantity" : 1.00
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

=> return:

```
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. Please choose an item to add.",
            "o:errorPath": "item.items[0]",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

The ways as per the documentation:

```
{
    "trandate":"2023-11-21",
    "startdate":"2023-11-21",
    "duedate":"2023-12-31",
    "memo": "This is apostman test!",
    "externalid":"PO000093",
    "salesrep":"209",
    "tranId": "T2023000024",
    "item":{
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "orderLine" : 1,
                "quantity" : 1.00
            },
            {
                "orderLine" : 2,
                "quantity" : 1.00
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Return:

```
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.6.1",
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "An unexpected error occurred. Error ID: lod29zoc1fx69m8xhmt5i",
            "o:errorCode": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a case at Netsuite and I'm waiting for an answer.
The alternative will be to create a stand alone invoice and link the line to the sales order.
Here is an example:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": "1957"
    },
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "account": {
                    "id": "307"
                },
                "amount": 2000.0,
                "description": "Testing invoicing",
                "item": {
                    "id": "578"
                },
                "orderDoc": {
                    "id": <your sales order id>
                },
                "orderLine": <your sales order line number>,
                "quantity": 1.0,
                "rate": 2000.0
            }
        ]
    },
    "memo": "Testing transformation alternative",
    "prevDate": "2023-10-30",
    "prevRep": 209,
    "salesEffectiveDate": "2023-10-30",
    "subsidiary": {
        "id": "5"
    },
    "tranDate": "2023-10-30",
    "tranId": "INV004 testing alternative - 0003"
}
```

Comment: Dis you get an answer from Netsuite ? I'm trying to create credit memos linked to invoices via rest and got the same errors as you. The method described above does'nt work for me, tje memo is created but not linked

Comment: Yes, the REST API isn't available with legacy tax. For the credit memo, you need to use a RESTlet because it isn't working. Or you can use suitetax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another thing not working with Netsuite REST. Would you by chance share the RESTlet ? I have no idea how to do that...