# Netsuite: Create a partial credit memo applied to an invoice with REST API

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to create a partial credit memo that will be applied to an invoice.
For example, I have a credit memo of 100€ and an invoice of 500€.

Normally, you should transform the invoice into a credit memo.
If there is no body, it works and the credit memo will have the same value as the invoice.
This isn't what I want. So I tried to transform the invoice with a body but there is the "Unexpected error" that is known.

It's possible to create a stand alone invoice and to match the line with the one from a sales order. It will result that it's like the invoice has been created from the sales order.
For more info: [NETSUITE: Getting error while transforming sales order into invoice with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77390072/netsuite-getting-error-while-transforming-sales-order-into-invoice-with-rest-ap)

I would like to know if it's possible to do it with the credit memo applied to an invoice ?
I tried different methods but it always returning an error

For example:

```
{
    "entity": { "id": "1957" },
    "trandate":"2023-11-21",
    "startdate":"2023-11-21",
    "duedate":"2023-12-31",
    "memo": "Testing to create credit memo",
    "salesrep":"209",
    "item":{
        "items":[
            {
                "description": "Test description",
                "item": {
                    "id": "632"
                },
                "quantity": 0.1,
                "rate": 2000.0,
                "line": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "apply": {
        "items" : [
            {
                "amount": 200,
                "apply": true,
                "doc": { 
                    "id" : 20067 => Sales order ID
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Return:

```
{
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.",
            "o:errorPath": "apply",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
```

If I change the way that I set the doc id:

```
{
    "entity": { "id": "1957" },
    "trandate":"2023-11-21",
    "startdate":"2023-11-21",
    "duedate":"2023-12-31",
    "memo": "Testing to create credit memo",
    "salesrep":"209",
    "item":{
        "items":[
            {
                "description": "Test description",
                "item": {
                    "id": "632"
                },
                "quantity": 0.1,
                "rate": 2000.0,
                "line": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "apply": {
        "items" : [
            {
                "amount": 200,
                "apply": true,
                "doc":  20067
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Return:

```
"status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Invalid value for the resource or sub-resource field 'doc'. Provide a valid value.",
            "o:errorPath": "doc",
            "o:errorCode": "INVALID_VALUE"
        }
    ]
```

I tried to add a line number of value 0, then of value 1, then remove doc, ...
It always return an error.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not sure that helps a lot but I got the same kind of error and solved the "Invalid value for the resource or sub-resource field 'doc'" error by writing "doc": { "id": "20067" }.

Comment: It didn't work for us so I created a RESTlet